# CORS issue though django-corsheaders is set up

Tags: django, angularjs, django-cors-headers

I'am getting an error message from Angular whenever I try to make an AJAX call to an endpoint of my backend (on a separate domain, running Django 1.7):

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

I do have `django-corsheaders` installed, `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` and the middleware set up properly. So what's wrong?

I am not sure if this information is relevant, but I am still testing everything on a single host, meaning there is one XAMPP server running for the Angular frontend at `localhost` and one Gunicorn instance running at `localhost:5000` for the backend.